# Why we need to set no_new_privs while before calling SECCOMP_MODE_FILTER?

Tags: linux, security, system-calls

At the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seccomp.2.html) I read the following line:

> cause an attempt to use setuid(2) to set the caller's user IDs to
>   nonzero values to instead return 0 without actually making the system
>   call

I can't understand what they are trying to say. Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks.

Comment: The example you are quoting decribes the sequence like the following. Some user program sets the `seccomp` filter up and calls, say, `sudo su someuser`, which escalates (temporarily) the thread privileges to the full capabilities set due to SUID bit on its binary. After this, `sudo` tries to change the UID to `someuser` (of course, assuming that the caller is really allowed to `sudo su someuser` in `sudoers`). If at this point the `seccomp` filter catches the `setuid(2)` call from `sudo` and immediately returns 0 instead of proceeding to the real call, the thread will stay privileged.

Comment: I.e. the unprivileged process sets up the filter which will then discard any attempts to "downgrade" the privileges of the process. After this, the process calls something that temporarily escalates the privileges (`sudo`) and happily stays with these privileges forever. Thus, to avoid such tricks, the thread which sets the filter has to have `no_new_privs`, which will forbid permissions escalation while calling things like SUID binaries.

Comment: Fix to the first post: "`su` tries to change the UID to `someuser`", of course, and "the `setuid(2)` call from `su`".

Comment: @DanilaKiver nice explanation. please post this as an answer :)

Comment: I will be able to post the detailed answer a bit later.

Comment: Done! Sorry for the delay, I was a bit busy this week. Also note, that I've changed the example to use only `sudo` alone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, notice the following paragraph at the `seccomp(2)` manpage:

> SECCOMP_RET_ERRNO
>
> This value results in the SECCOMP_RET_DATA portion of the filter's return value being passed to user space as the errno value without executing the system call.

So, the seccomp filter may make the kernel *skip* the real system call execution and instead [return some value](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8f8972a3127ff46df62ae30057d29606968ec4aa/kernel/seccomp.c#L824-L825) to *pretend* that the system call was executed and produced the specified result. This also covers the [*successful* result](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8f8972a3127ff46df62ae30057d29606968ec4aa/arch/x86/include/asm/syscall.h#L84-L89), if the return value is set to zero.

Here is the sample `libseccomp`–based program (`sec.c`) which shows how this works (all error checks are omitted for brevity):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <seccomp.h>

int main() {
    scmp_filter_ctx seccomp;

    seccomp = seccomp_init(SCMP_ACT_ALLOW);

    // Make the `openat(2)` syscall always "succeed".
    seccomp_rule_add(seccomp, SCMP_ACT_ERRNO(0), SCMP_SYS(openat), 0);

    // Install the filter.
    seccomp_load(seccomp);

    FILE *file = fopen("/non-existent-file", "r");

    // Do something with the file and then perform the cleanup.
    // <...>

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this program while tracing the execution shows that `openat(2)` system call returns zero (i.e. "executed" successfully) though the file `/non-existent-file` does not exist in the file system:

```bsh
$ gcc sec.c -lseccomp -o sec

# Run the program showing the openat(2) invocations and their results.
$ strace -e trace=openat ./sec
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/non-existent-file", O_RDONLY) = 0
...

# Ensure that the file does not exist.
$ stat /non-existent-file
stat: cannot stat '/non-existent-file': No such file or directory
```

Well, now we understand the capabilities of seccomp filters. Let's go closer to the point of the paragraph you've quoted in your question. Think about two things:

- there are some kernel mechanisms which may be employed by the unprivileged process to escalate its privileges;
- there are some tools which employ such mechanisms to grant the privileges *temporarily* and only for the restricted amount of operations.

The typical example is `sudo(8)` utility, which is the `root`–owned SUID binary. Executing it in the context of the unprivileged process grants the calling process the full superuser power (except some special cases like sandboxes and containers), after which `sudo(8)` checks the `/etc/sudoers` file to learn whether the calling user is allowed to perform the requested operation or not. If he is, `sudo(8)` proceeds with the execution, and if not, the execution is denied. Also, `sudo(8)` allows the execution on behalf of arbitrary user — in this case, it will [set the appropriate credentials before executing the requested operation](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/blob/47d95047164edfb173600248aa6068edb9351bfe/src/exec.c#L188-L207).

For example, assuming that the `/etc/sudoers` file contains the following record

```
testuser ALL=(anotheruser) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash
```

the user `testuser` will be able to run the shell on behalf of `anotheruser` with the following command:

```
sudo -u anotheruser -i /bin/bash
```

Now, we get closer to the point: what if `testuser`–owned process installs the seccomp filter, which makes the kernel return from `setuid(2)` without actually executing it, and then runs `sudo -u anotheruser -i /bin/bash`? Well, let's see:

- the kernel sees the SUID bit on the `sudo(8)` binary and escalates the privileges of the calling process appropriately;
- `sudo(8)` checks the `/etc/sudoers` and ensures that `testuser` is allowed to run `/bin/bash` as `anotheruser`;
- then `sudo(8)` calls `setuid(2)` to change the process' credentials appropriately and "downgrade" its privileges;
- the user-installed seccomp filter silently reports the success, pretending that the "downgrade" is finished;
- `sudo(8)` believes that the process now runs on behalf of `anotheruser` and proceeds with the execution of `/bin/bash`...
- actually running it with superuser privileges, because `setuid(2)` was skipped by the filter and was not really executed!

So, allowing the unprivileged user to install seccomp filters also allows this user to "hijack" the privileged credentials by catching the calls to `setuid(2)` while *temporarily* running with escalated privileges, hence there are the restrictions specified at the manpage:

> either the calling thread must have the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability in its user namespace, or the thread must already have the no_new_privs bit set.

It is clear what does the first part of this sentence mean: `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` is a capability which grants the process lots of privileges, so it is safe to assume that the process possessing it is already powerful enough to wreak the havoc in the system. What about the second part?

The `no_new_privs` bit is a property of the process which, if set, tells the kernel to *not* employ privileges escalation mechanisms like SUID bit (so, invoking things like `sudo(8)` will not work at all), so it is safe to allow the unprivileged process with this bit set to use seccomp filters: this process will not have any possibility to escalate privileges even temporarily, thus, will not be able to "hijack" these privileges.